# Claims authorization using Thinktecture.IdentityModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, claims-based-identity

As explained on [leastprivilege](http://leastprivilege.com/2012/10/26/using-claims-based-authorization-in-mvc-and-web-api/), there are two ways to setup Claims Authorization checks using Thinktecture.IdentityModel.  One is to setup a filter.  The other is to add attributes to the actions you want to check.

I'm successfully using the attributes option.  However, I'd like to override the behavior of sending unauthorized (but authenticated) requests to the login page.

Instead I'd like to simply present a 401 error (or an unauthorized page).  So far, I have the following class to override the HandleUnauthorizedRequest and throw the 401 error (if Authenticated).  However, the only way I've figured out how to wire it in is by adding this class as a filter.  By doing that though, it skips using the attribute decorations and only sends the action/resource through to the CheckAcess method, which is useless to us.

```
    public class CustomClaimsAuthorizeAttribute : Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Authorization.Mvc.ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute
{
    public CustomClaimsAuthorizeAttribute()
    {
    }

    public CustomClaimsAuthorizeAttribute(string action, params string[] resources)
        : base(action, resources)
    {
    }


    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Insufficent permissions.");

        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whoever may be interested.  I finally realized this is as (ridiculously) simple as using my own class name as the attribute.

```
CustomClaimsAuthorizeAttribute("myParameter")
public ActionResult Index()
{
  ...
}
```

Additionally, I found that even with the following in my web.config file, throwing the UnauthorizedAccessException won't present the specified 401 error page to the user.  Instead they receive the general error page.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.aspx">
   <error statusCode="401" redirect="ErrorNoAccess.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

This exception produces:

> "ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request
>   identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically
>   {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and
>   the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if
>   the application is not impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity will be
>   the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user."

I instead decided to throw a 403 (Forbidden) error.  So my override ended up looking like this:

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{

    if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        throw new HttpException((int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Unauthorized access");

    base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
}
```

And my web.config error pages specified as:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.aspx">
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="ErrorNoAccess.aspx" />
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="ErrorNotFound.aspx" />
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="ErrorPage.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

I can now log in as a user with insufficient privileges and be presented the ErrorNoAccess.aspx page instead of being thrown to the login page (which actually turned into a loop if I had 'remember me' checked).

I truely don't understand what MS was thinking by throwing the user to the login page because of a validly authenticated, but unauthorized request.  There's no feedback to the user as to why they would be thrown back to the login page and nothing to hint the user to try different credentials (which is highly unlikely they even have different credentials).